# Should I "Compile .py Files to Byte Code after Installation"?

Tags: python, python-3.x, installation

I'm installing Python 3.2 32bit on Win7 machine, there is the following option:

> Compile .py Files to Byte Code after Installation

Should I leave option unchecked or is the compilation recommended?

Comment: probably dont want to .. .at least if you want to beable to look at the source later..

Comment: @Joran: The act of compilation does not remove the source.

Comment: it doesnt make the pyc files?  I must have been mistaken thanks for clarifying @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams

Comment: It generates the .pyc (and .pyo) files, but it does not remove the .py files.

Comment: @JoranBeasley why wouldn't you be able to look at the source again?

Comment: related -> https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2000/04/12/choices/

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Since the bytecode is unlikely to change regardless of how many times it is compiled, the interpreter can take advantage of the small speedup gain. Unless you are *very* short of hard drive space, you should select this option.

Comment: I always assumed having they must be significant enought to warrant the interpreter going to the trouble of writing them and then checking for and possibly using them later.

Comment: I suppose it does at least prove that the compiler works on the processor...

Never hurts to know on exotic boxes.

Comment: tho' if you want (for some strange reason) to use this (as far as I understand internal Python) code in other versions, you should not choose this option due to optimization of byte code compilation (in future versions) and slightly different byte code generation generally between some versions, which can lead to ineffective interpretation, or maybe inability to run