# No default bytecode compilation of Python code on Windows?

Tags: python, installation, bytecode

I just ran into this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12376188/should-i-compile-py-files-to-byte-code-after-installation) and I'm baffled. I'd say I have a fair experience with Python, but only on *nux(-like) OSes and I thought bytecode compilation was a given.

I'm obviously missing something here: was something happening behind the curtain I didn't know about on my OSes, like some configuration defaults ? Is it only on Windows and then, why? Is there any reason why *not* to compile to bytecode?

Thanks a lot in advance for any opinion, I'm very curious.

Comment: Are you asking what "compiling to bytecode" means, or are you asking when/why you should or shouldn't do it?

Comment: Nope, I'm just saying that I always took for a given that my code would be compiled to `.pyc` at one point or another, and that I'm surprised there could be an option not to do it. But right, editing my question.

Comment: So what exactly is your question?

Comment: The answer mentions severe lack of hard drive space as being the only reason not to compile.  But I don't understand that rationale - does JIT compilation discard bytecodes after they are used?  If they are cached, then you'd use up the space after using Python the first time, instead of after installing it - not much of a savings.

Comment: @Dave That's why I'm surprised! Obviously I'm missing something, either misunderstanding the question I was linking to, or some basic difference between Windows and *nuxes, but I didn't want to hijack the original question by asking mine in the comments. Hence this one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically, it's offering to pre-compile the Python installation files to bytecode, which would normally happen the first time they're used. As I understand it, it's just intended as a general convenience to avoid that initial compilation on use.

It *would* potentially save space not compiling all of the files in the standard library, but that would last only as long as you didn't try to use them.

Comment: Only on Windows, or on other OSes too (and I missed it) ? And what convenience is this?

Comment: I only ever recall seeing it in the Windows installer. The convenience is in not having to wait the microseconds to compile to bytecode the first time you use a module.